# Multiple indexes query in Boost Multi-Index

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, boost-multi-index

I'm writing a software that stores **GenericOrder** (containing a quantity, a price, a way and a timestamp) as shared_ptr.
I've read Boost documentation and succeed to define a **MultiIndexOrderContainer** using three indexes: way, timestamp and price.
But I don't find a way to iterate on specific orders using multiple indexes at the same time.

```
#include <memory>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace ::boost;
using namespace ::boost::multi_index;

enum class Way
{
    UNDEFINED,
    BUY,
    SELL
};

template <typename QuantityType, typename PriceType>
struct GenericOrder
{
    explicit GenericOrder(const Way way, const QuantityType& quantity, const PriceType& price, const long long& timestamp)
        : way_(way), quantity_(quantity), price_(price), timestamp_(timestamp)
    {
    }

    ~GenericOrder() = default;
    GenericOrder(const GenericOrder&) = delete;
    GenericOrder& operator=(const GenericOrder&) = delete;

    Way way_;
    QuantityType quantity_;
    PriceType price_;
    long long timestamp_ = -1;
};

// Aliases
using QuantityType = int;
using PriceType = int;
using OrderType = GenericOrder<QuantityType, PriceType>;
using PointerType = std::shared_ptr<OrderType>;

struct way {};
struct timestamp {};
struct price {};

using MultiIndexOrderContainer = multi_index_container<PointerType,
    indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<tag<way>, member<OrderType, decltype(OrderType::way_), &OrderType::way_ >>,
    ordered_non_unique<tag<timestamp>, member<OrderType, decltype(OrderType::timestamp_), &OrderType::timestamp_ >>,
    ordered_non_unique<tag<price>, member<OrderType, decltype(OrderType::price_), &OrderType::price_>>
    >
>;

int main()
{
    MultiIndexOrderContainer c;

    // Inserting some orders
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::BUY, 10, 15, 0));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::BUY, 10, 14, 1));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::BUY, 10, 13, 2));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::SELL, 10, 16, 3));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::SELL, 10, 17, 4));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::SELL, 10, 18, 5));

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to iterate on:

1. On buying orders with a specific price sorted by timestamp
2. Cheapest order price from selling orders
3. Costliest order price from buying orders

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: You may use the sortered index of multi_index container with [boost::filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html).

Comment: @Jarod42, it may sounds a good idea but time complexity is linear. I'm using multi indexes for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost.MultiIndex does not provide any special mechanism for mixing the orders induced by different indices: with the structure you propose you're basically down to querying for the first parameter and then doing a linear scan on the returned range.

On the other hand, if your queries are always of the form (attr1, attr2, attr3) you can speed them up by using [composite keys](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#composite_keys). In your particular case, you can have the three queries you're after with a composite key on (`way_`,`price_`,`timestamp_`)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99ec5a560b2e7d7b)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace ::boost;
using namespace ::boost::multi_index;

enum class Way
{
    UNDEFINED,
    BUY,
    SELL
};

template <typename QuantityType, typename PriceType>
struct GenericOrder
{
    explicit GenericOrder(const Way way, const QuantityType& quantity, const PriceType& price, const long long& timestamp)
        : way_(way), quantity_(quantity), price_(price), timestamp_(timestamp)
    {
    }

    ~GenericOrder() = default;
    GenericOrder(const GenericOrder&) = delete;
    GenericOrder& operator=(const GenericOrder&) = delete;

    Way way_;
    QuantityType quantity_;
    PriceType price_;
    long long timestamp_ = -1;
};

template <typename QuantityType, typename PriceType>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const GenericOrder<QuantityType,PriceType>& o)
{
    switch(o.way_){
        case Way::UNDEFINED: os<<"UNDEFINED, ";break;
        case Way::BUY: os<<"BUY, ";break;
        case Way::SELL: os<<"SELL, ";break;
    }
    return os<<o.price_<<", "<<o.timestamp_<<"\n";
}

// Aliases
using QuantityType = int;
using PriceType = int;
using OrderType = GenericOrder<QuantityType, PriceType>;
using PointerType = std::shared_ptr<OrderType>;

struct way {};
struct timestamp {};
struct price {};

using MultiIndexOrderContainer = multi_index_container<PointerType,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_non_unique<
            composite_key<
                OrderType,
                member<OrderType, decltype(OrderType::way_), &OrderType::way_ >,
                member<OrderType, decltype(OrderType::price_), &OrderType::price_>,
                member<OrderType, decltype(OrderType::timestamp_), &OrderType::timestamp_ >
            >
        >
    >
>;

int main()
{
    MultiIndexOrderContainer c;

    // Inserting some orders
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::BUY, 10, 15, 0));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::BUY, 10, 14, 1));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::BUY, 10, 13, 2));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::BUY, 10, 15, 1));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::SELL, 10, 16, 3));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::SELL, 10, 17, 4));
    c.insert(std::make_shared<OrderType>(Way::SELL, 10, 18, 5));

    std::cout<<"Buying orders for 15, sorted by timestamp\n";
    auto p=c.equal_range(std::make_tuple(Way::BUY,15));
    while(p.first!=p.second)std::cout<<**p.first++;

    std::cout<<"Cheapest selling order\n";
    std::cout<<**c.lower_bound(Way::SELL);

    std::cout<<"Costliest buying order\n";
    std::cout<<**--c.upper_bound(Way::BUY);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm building up wrappers to use these functions and I'm taking a look into hashed indices on top of composite_key. Do you think it can be compatible ?

Comment: When using composite keys with hashed indices you have a limitation, namely that partial queries are not supported. For instance, if your composite key is on (attr1,attr2,attr3), you can't query for (attr1,attr2) (with ordered indices you can), only for the whole tuple.

Comment: Oh ok so, to take advantage of composite key and hashed indices, the only way is to duplicate indexes (one composite, one hashed) ?

Comment: It all depends on your query patterns. If you only look for, say (attr1,attr2) and (attr1,attr2,attr3), two hashed indices, one with composite_key(attr1,attr2) and the other with composite_key(attr1,attr2), can do. Of course when patterns are too many, adding more and more specific indices is not advisable... As always, measure and make your decisions accordingly.